# Calculating Distance between two coordinates using CLLocation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, cllocation

I'm using `CLLocationDistance` to get the distance between two points, but I'm getting an error when passing my current location in it.

```
CLLocation *current = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:startLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:startLocation.coordinate.longitude];
CLLocation *itemLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[[[getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]];

//Here the current location gives me an error "Initializing cllocation with an expression incompatible format"
CLLocationDistance *itemDist = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:current];
NSLog(@"Distance: %@", itemDist);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're getting is actually:

> Initializing 'CLLocationDistance *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'CLLocationDistance' (aka 'double')

What it's saying is you're initializing `itemDist` (which you've declared as a `CLLocationDistance *`) to something that is returning a `CLLocationDistance` (notice no asterisk).

`CLLocationDistance` is not an object.
It is just a primitive type (specifically `double` -- see the [Core Location Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW11)).

So instead of declaring `itemDist` as a *pointer* to a `CLLocationDistance`, just declare it as a `CLLocationDistance` (no asterisk):

```
CLLocationDistance itemDist = [itemLoc distanceFromLocation:current];
```

You'll also need to update the `NSLog` to expect a *double* instead of an *object* otherwise it will crash at run-time:

```
NSLog(@"Distance: %f", itemDist);
```

Answer (score 5):

Is swift 2.0 is in the following way:

```
let userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 11.11, longitude: 22.22)
let priceLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 33.33, longitude: 44.44)
let meters:CLLocationDistance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(priceLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you 
in view load

```
//************************** GEtting USer's latitude/ Longitude ********************




  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//************************** GEtting USer's latitude/ Longitude ********************
```

## pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {        
        CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:11.111111111111111 longitude:11.1111111111111111]; 
        User_Vanue_Distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
        NSLog(@"THIS IS THE DISTANCE BT TWO POINTS +++++++++++++++++++++%f",User_Vanue_Distance);  
    }
}
```

You need to put below keys in info.plist, in ios 8 to access location we need to put below keys in info.plist
1.    `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription    : Location required`
2. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription Needed   : Location Needed`

This will work for you but one thing you need to add is add a check for ios8. otherwise this will crash on ios 7

```
// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.


  if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
```

Hope this will work for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

**To find distance in KM from two different Lat & Long**

```
let userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.0320, longitude: 72.5250)
let priceLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.0283, longitude: 72.5067)
let distance = String(format: "%.2f km", userLocation.distanceFromLocation(priceLocation)/1000)
print("Distance is KM is:: \(distance)")
```